# CRITICAL: Read timed out after 10 seconds [] []

Tags: magento2, error

I am nothing to understand why show this error in magento system.log file

> CRITICAL: Read timed out after 10 seconds [] []

Answer (score 0):

Please check below :-

1. Seem that you were using the curl to work with API. Your issue relates to the timeout issue. Try to increase the timeout for your curl.
2. Cache problem. Maybe you are using varnish cache, please check the concurrent connection setting or try to restart Varnish.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown by Laminas\Http\Client.
So probably some code tried to connect to other services (external api, Elasticsearch, etc) and got timeout error.